# Java toggle button event not fired when selection is done but fired when mouse hovered

Tags: java, swing, togglebutton

I have a toggle button and I set its state as follows

```
 public void setSizeFeet(boolean enabled) {
        this.size_tb.setSelected(enabled);

   }
```

I have listener

```
size_tb.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            size_tbStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });
private void size_tbStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                     
     if (size_tb.isSelected()){
            size_tb.setText("Feet");
        } else {
            size_tb.setText("Meters");
        }
}
```

The problem that when I set the state calling the first method. Nothing happens. However, by just hovering the mouse over the button then it updates to show the correct text. I put a break a point and I noticed the event just fires when I hover the mouse over the button. Shouldn't it when the selection is set or when it is mouse click not hover)

Thanks

Comment: How can it be possible ? sounds strange. the toggle button should be had a mouse listener to do this.

Comment: `ChangeListener` is notified when internal model is change. When you hover the button, its rollover property is changed, so you get the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ActionListener:

```
new JToggleButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JToggleButton tBtn = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();
        if (tBtn.isSelected()) {
           System.out.println("button selected");
        } else {
           System.out.println("button not selected");
        }        
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can use the ItemListener:

```
 ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
    int state = itemEvent.getStateChange();
    if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
      System.out.println("Selected");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Deselected");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried that, the event only get generated when you click on button not when you do setSelected

Comment: I didnt try that. Thanks .I will accept it unless otherwise found :)